# Check if a div contains a perticular image

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, droppable

In [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkefk/32/), I would like to check whether a particular image is inside div or not.I tried.but is not working. How can i do this?

JS Code

```
          if($('#house0').find('#container'))
          {
             alert("blue image within container");
          }
          else {
            alert("Wrong!");
          }
```

Comment: How are you going to identify the image? Are you identifying it by just an `img` tag or is there a particularly element id or class associated with it?

Comment: you mean blue image  should within the container , it should not move out side the container ? is it?

Comment: @ColinSchoen I'm going to identify particular image is dropped into the container using image id

Comment: @Prog I want to check whether blue image is dropped into the container or not